# nVidia and SFML error

Tags: c++, opengl, sfml, glew

I have been working on a game using sfml + glew. It works fine on a Intel HD 530 iGPU but when I try to run it using a dedicated nVidia gpu (a gtx 1070 using the 381.65 drivers) it crashes and shows the following error message:

> Warning: Detected "Microsoft Corporation GDI Generic" OpenGL implementation
>   The current OpenGL implementation is not hardware-accelerated
>
> Warning: The created OpenGL context does not fully meet the settings that were requested
>
> Requested: version = 3.3 ; depth bits = 24 ; stencil bits = 8 ; AA level = 0 ; core = false ; debug = false ; sRGB = false
>
> Created: version = 1.1 ; depth bits = 32 ; stencil bits = 8 ; AA level = 0 ; core = false ; debug = false ; sRGB = false
>
> Setting vertical sync not supported

Here's my window initing code:

```
sf::ContextSettings settings;
settings.depthBits = 24;
settings.stencilBits = 8;
settings.antialiasingLevel = 0;
settings.majorVersion = 3;
settings.minorVersion = 3;
sf::RenderWindow globalWindow(sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode(),
    "OpenGL",
    sf::Style::Fullscreen,
    settings);
glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
glewInit();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: And have you tried to update nvidia's driver? It seems me that you are using the native drivers that come with windows installation

Comment: Yep. I am currently running the absolute latest drivers

Comment: Edit: For some strange reason I had nvoglv32.dll in the same folder as my executable. Removing this completly fixes everything